# Android: How to Send user to Install an App on Google Play Store and then Detect Install Start and progress

Tags: android, google-play

I'm looking to send a user to install an app from the Play Store, then once they click the install button I want to send them back to my app and show a progress bar and helpful info.

There is an app called Mistplay that does this. I know they detect the app installation, but I'm not sure if they are faking the app Install progress or not.

Any suggestions on this? I'm able to use intents to launch the play store market but I don't know how to detect the user clicking install in Play Store and sending the user back to my app or any of the steps past that.

Edit 1:

So I am able to detect when the installation finishes by including the target app in my Manifest Queries section + having this code  (overly verbose for testing) in my main activity onCreate() + onDestroy unregister.

```kotlin
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED)
        filter.addDataScheme("package")
        registerReceiver(appInstallBroadcastReceiver, filter)
```

Comment: This might be helpful - [Google Play Install Referrer](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer)

Comment: I've looked at that. My understanding was that it was the information of what referred YOUR OWN app to be installed. Am I understanding that incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller

Offers the ability to install, upgrade, and remove applications on the device. This includes support for apps packaged either as a single "monolithic" APK, or apps packaged as multiple "split" APKs.

An app is delivered for installation through a PackageInstaller.Session,...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is granted:

```
if ((mPm.checkUidPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES, installerUid)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        || (installerUid == Process.ROOT_UID)
        || mIsInstallerDeviceOwner) {
    mPermissionsAccepted = true;
} else {
    mPermissionsAccepted = false;
}
```

Later, Make your app the Device owner: [Refrence](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageInstallerSession.java)

Once app is device owner we can install apk without any user intervention:

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName)
        throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set package name in params and create a session
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    // open session
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    // Track install progress
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
    return true;
}


// Listens when install is complete
private static IntentSender createIntentSender(Context context, int sessionId) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                sessionId,
                new Intent(ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE),
                0);
        return pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
    }
```